# Server returning 'Not Found' for "www.host.com" but not "host.com"

Tags: dns, apache-httpd

My server is returning the correct paths for all of my domains as long as they are not prefixed with www. The following is one of my domains in it's simplest form:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName kyle-o.info
  ServerAlias www.kyle-o.info
  DocumentRoot /home/kyle/www/kyle-o.info
</VirtualHost>
```

I can provide logs if needed. The server is running Ubuntu:

```
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:   Ubuntu 12.10
  Release: 12.10
  Codename:   quantal
```

Comment: Does a DNS lookup on both the www-prefixed name and the non-prefixed name return the same IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DNS` `A` record for `www.kyle-o.info` is absent, so you need to fix the `DNS` to allow it to work as you expect:

```
$ dig kyle-o.info any

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1-RedHat-9.9.2-3.P1.fc17 <<>> kyle-o.info any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49816
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kyle-o.info.           IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.kyle-o.info. 1360369139 3600 900 1209600 10800
kyle-o.info.        7034    IN  A   192.81.212.242
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns2.digitalocean.com.
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns1.digitalocean.com.
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns3.digitalocean.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns3.digitalocean.com.
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns1.digitalocean.com.
kyle-o.info.        7200    IN  NS  ns2.digitalocean.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.digitalocean.com.   7028    IN  A   69.55.55.74
ns2.digitalocean.com.   7028    IN  A   141.0.175.217
ns3.digitalocean.com.   7028    IN  A   69.55.62.20
```

Comment: Isn't the ServerAlias supposed to handle that?

Comment: The ServerAlias lets Apache respond to different names. It doesn't create DNS records. Having the correct DNS record is a prerequisite.

Comment: @ott-- How would it handle a non-existent hostname? Contact the authoritative DNS server and register the name? The provided host name has to be resolvable to be useful. At best, the server could ignore the error and use the alias anyway, but far more common than the web server and outside clients having different ideas of the DNS namespace would simply be a mistype, which this error/warning *does* alert the administrator to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that @ would point both the domain and www-domain to the same IP? Anyways, I added an A record (not sure if it's done right): http://kyle-o.info/dns.png

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Could it be that the ServerAlias is meant for wildcard dns entries?

Comment: @slowBear Please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/145982) if it solved the problem

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This is not the right answer, the answer was adding a cname record.It looks to me like you're talking about an A record.

Comment: @slowBear `CNAME` or `A` is not important - both will let the thing to work properly (provided `CNAME` points to the resolvable name). You may add `A` record or `CNAME` - it is up to you. There is no standard that enforces you to use `CNAME` in this case. `CNAME` simplifies management tasks, but it is not a must. Also, `CNAME` leads to a subsequent query on the name it points to.

Comment: @Serge A `CNAME` RR doesn't necessarily have to lead to a subsequent query. It depends on what the CNAME points to and what the authoritative server is asked for and returns. But yes, *potentially* it can.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yes, I mean the potential case.